# Use visitor pattern to handle else if

Tags: c#, design-patterns, visitor-pattern

I wonder if there is any way to handle a simple condition with the visitor pattern or not?

For instance, if we have the below code, how can we apply the visitor pattern to it?

```
public class Elseif
{
    private int total;
    public int Condition(int x)
    {
        if(x==1)
        {
            total = 100;
        }
        else if(x==2)
        {
            total = 200;
        }
        return total;

    }
}
```

in other words how you want to write the overload for IVisitor interface ?

```
public interface IVisitor
{
    int Visitor(int x);
}
```

Comment: This is not a mission for the `visitor` pattern, and it's not possible as I see it.

Comment: Pattern - this is not what you need to pull on something, and it is necessary to make this what it was asking for a pattern.

Comment: Thanks, I know that I just looking for a way to hide elseIf to make my method single responsible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Visitor Pattern is for distinguishing different *types*, espacially if you have an object of an (abstract) superclass, and you want to do special things depending on the *concrete* type. That means, you can (and should) use it instead of an if-then-else with casting-tests.

The Visitor Pattern is not for distinguishing *values*.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you are looking for [Chain Of Responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) pattern?

Let's say your have to calculate bonus and you use something like this

```
public double GetBonusRate(int workingDays, int numberOfSales)
{
    if(numberOfSales > 20)
    {
      return 1.5;
    }

    if(workingDays >= 20 && numberOfSales > 10)
    {
      return 1.2;
    }

    if(numberOfSales > 5)
    {
      return 1.0;
    }

    if(workingDays > 10)
    {
      return 0.1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You expect, that number of conditions will grow and you realize, that adding new condition in a wrong place will cause a bug.
Chain of responsibility gives you another approach.

```
var chain = new PerfectBonusRate();
chain.RegisterNext(new GoodBonusRate())
    .RegisterNext(new StandartBonusRate())
    .RegisterNext(new LazyBonusRate())
    .RegisterNext(new NoBonusRate());

var bonusRate = chain.GetBonusRate(10, 20);
```

Implementation

```
abstract class ChainElement
{
    ChainElement _next;

    public ChainElement RegisterNext(ChainElement next)
    {
        _next = next;
        return next;
    }

    public double GetBonusRate(int workingDays, int numberOfSales)
    {
        if(IsMatched(workingDays, numberOfSales))
        {
            return GetBonusValue();
        }

        return _next.GetBonusRate(workingDays, numberOfSales);
    }

    protected abstract bool IsMatched(int workingDays, int numberOfSales);

    protected abstract int GetBonusValue();
}

class PerfectBonusRate : ChainElement
{
    protected override bool IsMatched(int workingDays, int numberOfSales)
    {
        return numberOfSales > 20;
    }

    protected override double GetBonusValue()
    {
        return 1.5;
    }
}

class GoodBonusRate : ChainElement
{
    protected override bool IsMatched(int workingDays, int numberOfSales)
    {
        return workingDays >= 20 && numberOfSales > 10;
    }

    protected override double GetBonusValue()
    {
        return 1.2;
    }
}

//and the same for StandartBonusRate, LazyBonusRate...

class NoBonusRate : ChainElement
{
    protected override bool IsMatched(int workingDays, int numberOfSales)
    {
        return true;
    }

    protected override double GetBonusValue()
    {
        return 0.0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Patterns used for solving some specific problems. Visitor pattern solves following problem - adding new capabilities to (composite) structure of objects without changing those objects. So, let me rephrase your question - *how can I add new capabilities to structure of objects, without having structure of objects and capabilities to be added*. That's like hammering nail with violin.

Remember - first goes problem. Then goes pattern which solves that problem. Not vice versa.

UPDATE so, what problem you code has? It does not follow [Command-query separation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-query_separation) principle. Same method performs an action (modifying total) and returns total to caller. I'd separated command and query to make your code more clear:

```
public int Total { get; set; }

public void DoSomething(int x)
{
    if(x == 1)
    {
        Total = 100;
        return;
    }

    if(x == 2)
    {
       Total = 200;
       return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, do you have any suggestion to get rid of elseif in this example ?

Comment: @wikinevis yes, I do - separate command and query. I'll add some code in a minute

Comment: Thanks, Now it follows CQRS in Tell don't ask manner but still doing two things. in fact I am looking for a way to get rid of else if to have single responsible method.

Comment: @wikinevis can you point those *two things* which code is doing?